# How to space columns evenly by the top icon and not by the text underneath the icon in a row

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a row of columns. I'm trying to space the space the columns evenly with regards to the icon and not the text. A picture might explain. better!

[image: Image of row].

From the image, the columns are spaced evenly with respect to the text...how would I make the columns spaced evenly with regards the icons. Do I need two different rows? Here is the code:

```
Container(
                      height: 60,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                      child: Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Column(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Icon(ChampionsMind.medal_light, size: iconSize, color: medalsColors[0]),
                              Text('RELIABILITY', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Column(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Icon(ChampionsMind.submenu_achievements, size: iconSize,
                                color: medalsColors[(Math.min(((userData.getPillarPoints(appData, 1) + userData.getPillarPoints(appData, 2) + userData.getPillarPoints(appData, 3) + userData.getPillarPoints(appData, 4))/6000), 1)*(medalsColors.length-1)).floor()],
                              ),
                              Text('MASTERY', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white), textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Column(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Icon(ChampionsMind.medal_light, size: iconSize, color: medalsColors[0]),
                              Text('TEAMWORK', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
```

Comment: Do all icons have the same width? If so you can try wrapping each Column with an Expanded widget, each of them using the same value for the `flex` property, eg. `flex: 1`. This will force the columns to take an equal amount of width within the Row. If the icons have varying widths, you will have to calculate what the value of `flex` should be for each column.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap icon and text inside SizedBox (or Container with width and height). So all buttons will be spaced evenly according to provided sizes.
In this way you may need adapt text size to fill available space and avoid text overflow (use FittedBox with fit: BoxFit.scaleDown).

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround
  children: [
    SizedBox(
      width: 48.0,
      height: 48.0,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Icon(ChampionsMind.medal_light, size: iconSize),
          FittedBox(fit: BoxFit.scaleDown, child: Text('RELIABILITY'))
        ]
      )
    ),
...
  ]
)
```

Also you can use MediaQuery to calculate width of buttons according to available screen space (final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / icons_count;).